# UICollectionViewCell willAppear not being called

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm trying to do a `UICollectionView` of articles that doesn't eats RAM like an elephant. So, the `UICollectionView` consists of full screen cells that contain one image. If the `UICollectionViewCell` appears, the content gets loaded in. This is the code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout=[[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    layout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal;
    layout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0;
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0;

    _collectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame collectionViewLayout:layout];
    [_collectionView setDataSource:self];
    [_collectionView setDelegate:self];
    _collectionView.pagingEnabled = YES;
    [_collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier"];
    [_collectionView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

    [self.view addSubview:_collectionView];
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    //add UIImageView here

    //add UITextView with tag 123 here

    return cell;
}

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView willDisplayCell:(UICollectionViewCell *)cell forItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [_collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    UITextView *textView = [cell viewWithTag:123];

    textView.text = @"Testing this out.";
}
```

However, this doesn't do anything. No errors are thrown, it just doesn't do anything. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you see red? Where are the rest of the data source methods?

Comment: No, I see the cells with the images in it, but not the text. The other `UICollectionView` source methods weren't needed for this question.

Comment: Keep in mind that memory usage is different on a device from the Simulator ... Always test on a device! You're missing the point of dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier. The Cell will be reused, so memory should not be an issue, old/scrolled out cells will be "nil"'d as needed. So for your text, simply set it where you set the image. To keep the UI from blocking, set the image in a background thread with the update happening on the main Thread. This should resolve any issues you have